# Convert RGB to black OR white

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

How would I take an RGB image in Python and convert it to black and white? Not grayscale, I want each pixel to be either fully black (0, 0, 0) or fully white (255, 255, 255).

Is there any built-in functionality for getting it done  in the popular Python image processing libraries? If not, would the best way be just to loop through each pixel, if it's closer to white set it to white, if it's closer to black set it to black?

Comment: I don't know Python, but [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) and [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) may be helpful

Comment: @WangYudong OpenCV is mad overkill for this

Comment: @NickT I was actually hoping to figure it out with OpenCV because the rest of my script is using OpenCV for Hough line transform. Still haven't figured out how to do that in PIL... Or how to convert between PIL and OpenCV for that matter.

Comment: @Tom Does `img = opencv.adaptors.PIL2Ipl(pilimg)` work for converting to an opencv image you can use?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

## Scaling to Black and White

Convert to grayscale and then scale to white or black (whichever is closest).

Original:

[image: meow meow tied up cat]

Result:

[image: Black and white Cat, Pure]

### Pure Pillow implementation

Install `pillow` if you haven't already:

```
$ pip install pillow
```

[Pillow](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) (or PIL) can help you work with images effectively.

```
from PIL import Image

col = Image.open("cat-tied-icon.png")
gray = col.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
bw.save("result_bw.png")
```

Alternatively, you can use [Pillow](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

### Pillow + Numpy Bitmasks Approach

You'll need to install numpy:

```
$ pip install numpy
```

Numpy needs a copy of the array to operate on, but the result is the same.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

col = Image.open("cat-tied-icon.png")
gray = col.convert('L')

# Let numpy do the heavy lifting for converting pixels to pure black or white
bw = np.asarray(gray).copy()

# Pixel range is 0...255, 256/2 = 128
bw[bw < 128] = 0    # Black
bw[bw >= 128] = 255 # White

# Now we put it back in Pillow/PIL land
imfile = Image.fromarray(bw)
imfile.save("result_bw.png")
```

## Black and White using Pillow, with dithering

Using [pillow](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) you can convert it directly to black and white. It will look like it has shades of grey but your brain is tricking you! (Black and white near each other look like grey)

```
from PIL import Image 
image_file = Image.open("cat-tied-icon.png") # open colour image
image_file = image_file.convert('1') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('/tmp/result.png')
```

Original:

[image: meow meow color cat]

Converted:

[image: meow meow black and white cat]

## Black and White using Pillow, without dithering

```
from PIL import Image 
image_file = Image.open("cat-tied-icon.png") # open color image
image_file = image_file.convert('1', dither=Image.NONE) # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('/tmp/result.png')
```

Comment: Must admit that the cat is much cuter without dithering.

Comment: You were just lucky that the levels worked out, this could have been very ugly indeed. And I'm sure PIL (and pillow?) have a way to do thresholding without resorting to Numpy.

Comment: There's got to be and boy am I a glutton for refactoring code. Feel free to edit to your heart's content if you find it. :)

Comment: @MarkRansom - Nice edit! Think it's ok to move your tighter code up to the top and only provide the numpy part for flexibility?

Comment: The `lambda` approach is going to make a Python function call for every pixel of the image, it's going to be unnecessarily slow when compared to numpy's boolean masking.

Comment: @Jaime, no it doesn't - the `point` function caches the return values from the function, so it will only be called 256 times at most.

Comment: @Kyle, it's your answer, do whatever you want!

Comment: Well now you've nerd sniped me and I'm going to have to look at performance. Sadly the numpy one has to make a copy (asarray returns a readonly copy).

Comment: @MarkRansom Ah, clever!

Comment: You can use `.convert('1', dither=Image.NONE)` to get result without dithering :)

Comment: I am not getting black and white but red and blue for the second approach, why is that? I did bw[bw<50] = 0
bw[bw>=50] = 255
mfile = Image.fromarray(bw)
plt.imshow(mfile)

Comment: Almost asked another question but found your answer. Using `bw = im_gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<255 else 255, '1')` does the job!

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest converting to grayscale, then simply applying a threshold (halfway, or mean or meadian, if you so choose) to it.

```
from PIL import Image

col = Image.open('myimage.jpg')
gry = col.convert('L')
grarray = np.asarray(gry)
bw = (grarray > grarray.mean())*255
imshow(bw)
```

Comment: @Tom Did you change the value to compare to?  Say, `grarray > 16` e.g.

Answer (score 3):

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(threshi, img_bw) = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pillow, with dithering

Using [pillow](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow) you can convert it directly to black and white. It will look like it has shades of grey but your brain is tricking you! (Black and white near each other look like grey)

```
from PIL import Image 
image_file = Image.open("cat-tied-icon.png") # open colour image
image_file = image_file.convert('1') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('/tmp/result.png')
```

Original:

[image: meow meow color cat]

Converted:

[image: meow meow black and white cat]

Comment: I don't want those gaps in-between the pixels though

Comment: Those "gaps" are white pixels.

Comment: Well no look at the top bar in the original image. It is a solid color, but when converted it somehow picks up those white pixels.

Comment: @Tom, the "gaps" are known as dithering and you probably won't like the results without it. I didn't know Pillow did that by default!

Comment: In this case I would actually need to disable this dithering. Is that possible?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, changed the image to a smaller cat picture instead of my mondo Jenkins pic. Want me to change it back?

Comment: Note that you'll be able to zoom in better directly on [the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LsIJ0.png).

Comment: @Tom - OH! I understand now. Yeah, we're going to need another solution. Let me do some more digging, though you may beat me to it reading the Pillow docs.

Answer (score 1):

And you can use `colorsys` (in the standard library) to convert rgb to [hls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and use the lightness value to determine black/white:

```
import colorsys
# convert rgb values from 0-255 to %
r = 120/255.0
g = 29/255.0
b = 200/255.0
h, l, s = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r, g, b)
if l >= .5:
    # color is lighter
    result_rgb = (255, 255, 255)
elif l < .5:
    # color is darker
    result_rgb = (0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using opencv You can easily convert rgb to binary image

```
import cv2
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = io.imread('http://www.bogotobogo.com/Matlab/images/MATLAB_DEMO_IMAGES/football.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
imR=img[:,:,0] #only taking gray channel
print(img.shape)
plt.imshow(imR, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))

#Gray Image
plt.imshow(imR)
plt.title('my picture')
plt.show()

#Histogram Analyze

imgg=imR
hist = cv2.calcHist([imgg],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.hist(imgg.ravel(),256,[0,256])

# show the plotting graph of an image

plt.show()

#Black And White
height,width=imgg.shape
for i in range(0,height):
  for j in range(0,width):
     if(imgg[i][j]>60):
        imgg[i][j]=255
     else:
        imgg[i][j]=0

plt.imshow(imgg)
```

Comment: When using NumPy, you should avoid loops. It can be written as ``imgg[ imgg< 60 ] = 0`` and ``imgg[ imgg >= 60 ] = 255``

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for creating binary image using opencv-python :

```
img = cv2.imread('in.jpg',2)

ret, bw_img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow("Output - Binary Image",bw_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use cv methods for the segmentation and understand what you are doing, treat the RGB image as matrix.

```
image = mpimg.imread('image_example.png') # your image
R,G,B = image[:,:,0], image[:,:,1], image[:,:,2] # the 3 RGB channels
thresh = [100, 200, 50] # example of triple threshold

# First, create an array of 0's as default value
binary_output = np.zeros_like(R)
# then screen all pixels and change the array based on RGB threshold.
binary_output[(R < thresh[0]) & (G > thresh[1]) & (B < thresh[2])] = 255
```

The result is an array of 0's and 255's based on a triple condition.