# python raster image HEX code

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, raster

I work currently with a thermal printer using ESCPOS command set.

I got this image:

[image: logo]

And they gave me the correct HEX code I have to sent to the printer to print the image above. The code from the picture above:

```
10 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F FF FF FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF FF FF FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FF FF FF FF F8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F FF FF FF FF FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF FF FF FF FF FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 FF FF FF FF FF FF F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FF FF FF FF FF FF FC 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 3F FF FF B0 00 7F FF FF 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 7F FF F0 10 00 07 FF FF 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF FF 80 08 00 01 FF FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF FC F9 E8 00 00 3F FF E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FF E0 00 18 00 00 0F FF F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F FF C0 00 00 00 00 03 FF FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F FC 00 00 00 00 08 00 7F FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF F8 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F FF 80 00 00 00 00 01 FF E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FF C0 00 00 00 00 03 FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF E0 00 00 00 00 07 FF 00 00 00 00 00 0E 00 01 FF F0 00 00 00 00 0F FE 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 FF F8 00 00 00 00 0F F8 00 00 00 00 00 1C 00 00 7F FC 00 00 00 00 1F F0 00 00 00 00 00 18 27 00 3F FC 00 00 00 00 3F E0 00 00 00 00 1F FF FF 40 1F FE 00 00 00 00 7F F0 00 00 00 01 FF FF FF F0 0F FF 00 00 00 00 FF A0 00 00 00 1F FF FF FF FF 07 FF 80 00 00 00 FF 20 00 00 00 7F FF FF FF FF C3 FF 80 00 00 01 FF 40 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF F1 FF C0 00 00 03 FF 40 00 00 07 FF FF FF FF FF F8 FF C0 00 00 03 FE 40 00 00 1F FF FF FF FF FF FC FF E0 00 00 07 FE 80 00 00 7F FF FF FF FF FF FE 7F F0 00 00 07 FC 80 00 01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 3F F8 00 00 0F F3 00 00 07 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF BF F8 00 00 0F F6 00 00 1F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF DF FC 00 00 1F EC 00 00 3F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF CF FC 00 00 1F E8 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF EF FE 00 00 3F C8 00 03 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F7 FE 00 00 3F 88 00 07 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F7 FE 00 00 3F 88 00 1F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FB FF 00 00 7F 08 00 3F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FB FF 00 00 7F 30 00 7F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FD FF 00 00 FF 40 01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FD FF 80 00 FE 40 03 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FE FF 80 00 FE 40 07 FF FF FF FF FF F3 FF FF FF FE FF 80 01 FC 40 0F FF FF FF FF FE 03 FF FF FF FE FF C0 01 FC 80 1F FF FF FF FF C0 03 FF FF FF FE 7F C0 03 FC 80 3F FF FF FF FE 00 03 FF DF FF FE 7F C0 0F FD 00 7F FF FF FF F8 00 03 FF C7 FF FE 7F E0 0B F8 00 FF FF FF FF E0 00 03 FF C7 FF FF 3F E0 13 FA 00 FF FF FF FF C0 00 03 FF C7 FF FE 3F E0 17 FE 01 FF FF FF FF FC 00 03 FF C7 FF FF 3F E0 17 F8 03 FF FF FF FF FF 00 03 FF C3 FF FE 3F E0 17 F0 03 FF FF FF FF FF C0 03 FF C3 FF FE 1F F0 17 F0 07 FF FF FF FF FF E0 03 FF C3 FF FE 1F F0 17 F0 07 FF FF FF FF FF E0 03 FF C3 FF FE 1F F0 17 F0 0F FF FF FF FF FF F0 03 FF C3 FF FE 1F F0 0F F0 0F FF FF FB FF FF F8 03 FF C3 FF FE 1F F0 0F F0 1F FF FF E7 FF FF F8 03 FF C3 FF FE 1F F0 0F F0 1F FF FF C7 FF FF FC 03 FF C3 FF FE 1F F8 0F F0 1F FF FF 8F FF FF FC 03 FF C3 FF FE 0F F8 0F F0 1F FF FF 1F FF FF FE 03 FF C3 FF FE 0F F8 0F F0 1F FF FE 3F FF FF FE 03 FF C3 FF FE 0F F8 0F F0 3F FF FE 1F FF FF FE 03 FF C3 FF FE 0F F8 0F F0 1F FF FC 3F FF BF FE 03 FF C1 FF FE 0F F8 0F F0 1F FF F8 3F FE 1F FE 03 FF C1 FF FE 0F F8 0F F0 1F FF F8 3F FC 1F FE 03 FF C1 FF FE 0F F8 0F F0 1F FF F0 3F FD DF FE 03 FF C1 FF FE 0F F8 07 F0 3F FF F0 3F F9 5F FE 07 FF C1 FF FE 0F F8 07 F0 1F FF F0 3F F9 5F FE 07 FF C1 FF FE 0F F8 07 F0 1F FF E0 7F F9 5F FF 0F FF C1 FF FE 0F F8 07 F0 1F FF E0 BF F9 5F FF FF FF 81 FF FE 0F F8 07 F0 1F FF E0 BF F9 5F FF FF FF 81 FF FE 0F F8 07 F0 1F FF E0 BF F9 DF FF FF FF 81 FF FE 1F F8 07 F0 3F FF E0 BF F8 DF FF FF FF 81 FF FE 1F F8 07 F0 3F FF E0 BF F8 1F FF FF FF 81 FF F8 1F F0 07 F0 3F FF E0 BF F8 0F FF FF FF 01 FF C0 1F F0 07 F0 3F FF E0 BF F9 CF FF FF FE 01 FE 00 3F F0 07 F0 3F FF E0 BF F9 6F FF FF FC 00 F0 00 3F F0 03 F0 3F FF E0 BF F9 37 FF FF FC 00 00 00 3F F0 03 F0 3F FF E0 BF F9 17 FF FF F8 00 00 00 3F F0 03 F8 3F FF E0 BF F9 13 FF FF F0 00 00 00 3F F0 03 F8 3F FF E0 BF F9 09 FF FF E0 00 00 00 3F E0 03 F8 3F FF E0 FF F9 0C 7F FF E0 01 00 00 7F E0 01 F8 3F FF E0 3F F9 06 3F FF 10 03 80 00 7F E0 01 FC 3F FF E0 3F F9 03 0F FC 60 01 C0 00 7F E0 01 FC 3F FF E0 3F F9 00 E0 01 80 01 C0 00 7F C0 01 FE 3F FF E0 3F F9 00 37 FE 00 08 80 00 FF C0 00 FE 3F FF E0 3F F9 00 18 00 00 00 00 01 FF C0 00 FE 3F FF E0 3F F9 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF 80 00 FE 3F FF E0 3F F9 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF 80 00 FF 3F FF E0 3F F9 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF 80 00 7F 3F FF E0 3F F9 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF 00 00 7F FF FF E0 3F F9 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF 00 00 3F FF FF E0 1F E1 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 FF 00 00 3F FF FF E0 1F C9 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 FE 00 00 3F FF FF E0 10 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FE 00 00 1F FF FF C0 08 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FC 00 00 1F FF FF 80 07 FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F FC 00 00 0F FF FE 01 81 F2 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F F8 00 00 0F FF E0 00 01 F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F F8 00 00 07 FF 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F F0 00 00 07 FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F F0 00 00 03 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF E0 00 00 03 FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF E0 00 00 01 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF C0 00 00 00 FF 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF 80 00 00 00 FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 FF 80 00 00 00 7F C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FF 00 00 00 00 3F F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F FE 00 00 00 00 1F F8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F FC 00 00 00 00 0F FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F FC 00 00 00 00 0F FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF F8 00 00 00 00 07 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF F0 00 00 00 00 03 FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF E0 00 00 00 00 01 FF E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 FF F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F FF 80 00 00 00 00 00 7F FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 1F FF 80 00 00 00 00 03 FF FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 FF E0 C0 00 00 00 1F FF F8 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF F9 3E 00 00 00 7F FF E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 FF FF 83 FE 40 1F FF FF C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F FF FF E0 CF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F FF FF FF FF FF FF FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F FF FF FF FF FF FF FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 FF FF FF FF FF FF E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF FF FF FF FF FF 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 1F FF FF FF FF FE 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 FF FF FF FF FF FF F0 00 00 00 00
```

They told me to use 'raster images' to generate code. I don't find any solution returning me the correct code for the image above.

Any idea how to get a function returning the code above when entering the picture I showed above?

Answer (score 4):

The raster data you've been given is 128 lines of 16 bytes each, with a lead 2 bytes setting the raster size (128 x 128). Each bit is either 0 or 1 defining *don't print* (white) or *print* (e.g. black), e.g. a simple black-and-white format.

It appears that the bytes are encoding pixels *from top to bottom* rather than from left-to-right as the bytes you produced otherwise would build a flipped and rotated image:

[image: raster image, inverted]

but if you take the data as most-significant bit is *top left* and following bits going down rather than right you get:

[image: raster image, decoded]

You'd have to generate the same data yourself from an image, once you converted it to black-and-white. Read the black-and-white image data from top to bottom, line by line, based on a PIL Image `'1'` mode image. If you transpose the image (flip and rotate) you can put the columns into rows and get the required bytes in one step using `Image.tobytes()` and use the `1;I` mode for the raw encoder to produce the inverted data:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
img = Image.open("original.png")
bwimg = img.convert('1')
transposed = bwimg.transpose(Image.ROTATE_270).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
data = bytearray(transposed.size)
data.extend(transposed.tobytes('raw', '1;I'))
```

Once you have a black-and-white image (mode `1`) in the right orientation, all you have to do is take the size as the first 2 bytes, and the `tobytes()` method produces the raw image data (1 bit per pixel).

The `'1;I'` mode for the raw encoder produces 0 for white, 1 for black instead of the default 0 for black, 1 for white mode, see the [raw modes table](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/writing-your-own-file-decoder.html).

For your input image (which is slightly different from the raster data you have been given), that produces:

```
80 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff ff c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f ff ff fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 ff ff ff ff f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f ff ff ff ff fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff fb 7f ff ff 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff fd 00 00 3f ff e0 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 07 ff a0 00 00 03 ff fc 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 1f fc 00 00 00 00 7f fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00 1f ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff c0 00 00 00 00 07 ff 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 80 00 00 00 00 01 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 00 00 03 f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f e0 00 00 00 00 07 e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f e0 00 00 00 00 0f c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f f0 00 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 fc 00 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 00 00 09 bf fc 00 03 fc 00 00 00 00 3e 00 00 00 00 00 76 40 13 e0 01 fe 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00 00 0b 89 bf fd 1c 00 fe 00 00 00 00 7a 00 00 00 00 74 77 ff ff f3 80 ff 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00 00 00 8b df ff ff fe 60 7f 80 00 00 01 f0 00 00 00 03 6d ff ff ff ff b0 3f 80 00 00 01 f0 00 00 00 1c bf ff ff ff ff c8 3f e0 00 00 03 e0 00 00 00 23 7f ff ff ff ff f8 1f e0 00 00 03 c0 00 00 01 dd ff ff ff ff ff fc 0f f0 00 00 07 e0 00 00 02 2f ff ff ff ff ff ff 0f f0 00 00 07 80 00 00 0d 7f ff ff ff ff ff fd 07 f8 00 00 0f 80 00 00 25 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 47 f8 00 00 0f 00 00 00 57 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 83 f8 00 00 1f 00 00 01 9f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff c3 fc 00 00 1e 00 00 02 7f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff a1 fc 00 00 3c 00 00 0d ff ff ff ff eb 6f ff ff f0 fc 00 00 3e 00 00 12 ff ff ff fe bc b1 ff ff c0 fe 00 00 3c 00 00 67 ff ff ff db 67 de 3f ff f8 fe 00 00 78 00 00 1f ff ff ff 66 91 63 cf ff e8 7f 00 00 7c 00 01 af ff ff f9 b8 00 9d 73 ff f0 7e 00 00 78 00 02 7f ff ff ae 80 01 7b 9d ff fc 3f 80 00 f8 00 04 ff ff fe d9 00 01 3e 06 ff e8 3f 00 00 f0 00 0b ff ff f7 60 00 00 fb 82 ff f8 3f 80 00 f0 00 11 ff ff fa 80 00 01 3e 03 7f ec 3f 80 01 f0 00 2f ff ff cc 00 00 01 7b 01 7f f8 1f 80 01 e0 00 47 ff ff 70 00 00 01 7d 03 3f ec 1f c0 01 e0 00 3f ff fe 80 00 00 01 3a 01 ff f0 1f c0 03 e0 00 9f ff f9 43 e8 00 01 ff 81 3f fc 1f c0 01 e0 01 7f ff ee 0c 14 00 00 3a 01 bf e8 0f c0 03 e0 00 3f ff f0 13 ff 80 01 bd 01 5f f4 0f e0 03 c0 03 ff ff a8 4f fe 40 01 7b 01 bf f8 0f c0 03 e0 00 7f ff 60 bf ff 80 00 be 00 bf ec 0f e0 07 c0 07 ff fe 81 2f ff 60 01 3b 01 5f f4 0f e0 03 e0 01 ff fd 80 ff ff d0 01 fe 80 bf f8 0f e0 07 c0 0d ff fa 02 7f ff a0 00 3b 00 bf ec 07 e0 03 e0 03 ff f4 01 ff ff f8 01 bd 01 5f f4 0f e0 07 c0 0b ff fa 05 fe df c0 01 7b 00 bf f8 07 f0 03 e0 0d ff d4 0b f5 27 f8 00 be 00 bf f4 07 e0 07 c0 03 ff e8 09 fe bb d8 01 3b 00 bf ec 07 e0 03 e0 0b ff d0 07 d0 05 e8 01 fe 81 5f f8 07 f0 07 c0 0b ff 60 1b e8 0b d4 00 3b 00 bf f4 07 e0 03 e0 07 ff 80 03 b0 0b f8 01 be 00 bf f8 07 f0 07 c0 0b ff e0 1f e0 09 cc 01 7b 00 bf ec 07 e0 03 e0 0b fe 80 03 b0 0f f0 01 3d 80 bf f4 07 f0 07 c0 05 ff 40 1b d0 01 dc 02 fe 00 bf f8 07 e0 03 c0 0b ff 80 17 a0 1b e8 01 3b 00 bf ec 07 e0 07 e0 0b fe c0 13 f0 0b f4 06 fd 00 bf f4 07 f0 03 c0 07 ff 00 17 90 09 ee 99 fe 00 bf b8 07 e0 07 e0 0b ff c0 13 e0 0f fb e6 f5 00 b6 d4 0f e0 03 c0 0b fe 80 1f b0 01 fc 1b fa 00 bf 68 07 e0 03 e0 15 ff 40 03 50 0b ff ef ec 00 a9 00 0f c0 03 c0 0b ff 80 1f e0 05 ff bf f4 00 de 00 0f e0 03 e0 0b fe c0 03 b0 02 ff ff d8 00 20 00 0f e0 03 c0 17 ff 00 1f d0 03 7f ff f0 00 00 00 0f c0 01 e0 09 ff c0 03 60 00 ff ff 50 00 00 00 0f e0 03 e0 17 fe 80 1f d0 03 3f ff a0 00 00 00 0f c0 01 e0 0b ff 40 03 b0 00 df fa c0 00 00 00 1f c0 01 f0 15 ff 80 1f d0 00 2f ed 00 00 00 00 1f c0 01 f0 0b fe c0 03 60 00 12 b4 00 00 00 00 3f 80 00 f0 17 ff 40 1f d0 00 0a a8 00 00 00 00 1f c0 00 f0 09 ff 80 03 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 80 00 f8 17 ff 40 1f e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 80 00 f8 0b fe 80 03 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 00 00 7c 15 ff c0 1f 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 00 00 7c 0b ff 00 03 e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 7c 17 ff c0 1f d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fe 00 00 3c 09 fe 80 03 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fe 00 00 3e 17 ff 40 1d e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fe 00 00 3e 0b ff c0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 00 00 1e 15 fe 80 0c 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 00 00 1f 0b ff 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 f8 00 00 0f 97 fa 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 f8 00 00 0f 89 a5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 f0 00 00 07 96 fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 f0 00 00 07 eb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f e0 00 00 03 e4 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f e0 00 00 03 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f c0 00 00 01 f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 80 00 00 01 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f c0 00 00 00 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 00 7e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fe 00 00 00 00 3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 00 00 00 00 1f 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 fa 00 00 00 00 0f 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 f8 00 00 00 00 07 e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f f0 00 00 00 00 07 e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f e0 00 00 00 00 03 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f d0 00 00 00 00 01 fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f c0 00 00 00 00 00 fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff 00 00 00 00 00 03 ff c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f c0 00 00 00 00 0f ff 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00 5f fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f fe 80 00 00 0b ff f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 ff fa 20 8a ff ff f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 ff ff ff ff f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 ff ff ff fe a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 92 aa 80 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

or the image:

[image: final result]

You may need to tweak how you convert from your colour or grayscale image to black-and-white to achieve better effects. My Ninja avatar becomes:

[image: Ninja]

with this process. Both these images have been rotated / flipped back to represent the image data as it would be printed.

Comment: Get exactly the same code as the support gave me isn't possible? They gave me a link to this .pdf and told me to take a look at page 83: [link](http://www.pdfhost.net/index.php?Action=Download&File=51f2b58395598c4817f0597403a5b2ae) Is the solution above in the right way?

Comment: @user3714446: the link you gave me doesn't work for me; I get a blank response (no title for the PDF, the actual PDF link is 0 bytes).

Comment: @user3714446: support used a different method to convert your image to black and white (a rather crude method, by the looks of it); there are additional splodges and lines on there that your source image just doesn't have.

Comment: Oh excuse me. This one should work fine I guess.    [link](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9345078/ESC-POS-Command-Guide.pdf.html)

Comment: @user3714446: see [Convert RGB to black OR white](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18777873) for some more options to convert to pure black and white.

Comment: I made this library in Python https://github.com/benoitguigal/python-epson-printer. It handles both image conversion to bitmap and ESCPOS raster printing. You may find it useful.