# Is there a function to transform all element of ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I must transform all elements of an ndarray (a grayscale image). In particular if I have the value 0 the desired value is 0 and the values > 0 become 1.
Is there a function of numpy that do this?
I can do this by two for but I think that it isn't the best solution.

Comment: like this? `myarr[myarr > 0] = 1`

Comment: like this myarr[myarr>0] = 1

Answer (score 1):

You should look up fancy indexing and/or boolean indexing in numpy.
Effectively what you can do is as such

```
array[array>0] = 1
```

This will set all indices > 0 to 1

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to work "in-place" you can do:

```
def to_bw(img, dtype=np.uint8):
    return (img > 0).astype(dtype)
```

e.g. you use this as:

```
import numpy as np

to_bw(np.array([0,1,2]))
```

it will evaluate to:

```
array([0, 1, 1])
```

note this sounds pretty similar to: [Convert RGB to black OR white](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18777873/1358308)