# Convert Matplotlib Figure to greyscale and b&w numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting some time series, which will be further used as an input into CNN. I need to convert the plot into NumPy array of greyscale and b&w formats.
Here is the part of the code that plots the time series:

```
    data = np.array([88, 70, 88.67903235, 50, 20, 88.66447851, 70, 88.65119164, 60]) 
    time = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

    f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi = 100)

    ax = f.add_axes([0,0,1,1])        
    ax.set_ylim(time[0], time[len(time)-1])        
    ax.set_xlim(0, 150)

    # y axis should be inverted
    ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])    

    ax.plot(data, time, "black")

    ax.axis('off')
```

The code above produces this image:

[image]

I need to convert it into the numpy array of greyscale and b&w format.

**UPDATE**

I have integrated some of the other answers into the by adding the following lines:

```
f.tight_layout(pad=0)
ax.margins(0)
f.canvas.draw()

image_from_plot = np.frombuffer(f.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
image_from_plot = image_from_plot.reshape(f.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
```

Unfortunately, it gives me something different, with squeezed in vertical boundaries

[image]

Comment: some thing like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821518/matplotlib-save-plot-to-numpy-array)?

Comment: probably, but I couldn't find b&w or greyscale conversion steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers from the following posts on [conversion to RGB array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821518/matplotlib-save-plot-to-numpy-array) and [conversion to grayscale and/or b&w array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777873/convert-rgb-to-black-or-white), I have managed to solve the problem with the following code:

```
DPI = 300

# data sample
data = np.array([88, 70, 88.67903235, 50, 20, 88.66447851, 70, 88.65119164, 60]) 
time = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

# plot the figure without axes and margins 
f = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3), dpi = DPI)
ax = f.add_axes([0,0,1,1])    # remove margins       
ax.set_ylim(time[0], time[len(time)-1])    # y limits
ax.set_xlim(0, 150) # x limits
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])    # invert y-axis
ax.plot(data, time, "black")    # plot the line in black
ax.axis('off')    # turn off axes


import io
io_buf = io.BytesIO()
f.savefig(io_buf, format='raw', dpi=DPI)
io_buf.seek(0)
img_arr = np.reshape(np.frombuffer(io_buf.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8),
                  newshape=(int(f.bbox.bounds[3]), int(f.bbox.bounds[2]), -1))


from PIL import Image
col = Image.fromarray(img_arr) # RGB image
gray = col.convert('L') # grayscale image
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1') # b&wimage

# saving
path = "C:/Users/<id>/<folder>/"

bw.save(path+"result_bw.png")
gray.save(path+"result_gray.png")
col.save(path+"result_col.png")
```